# Case Insensitive String comparison in lightning aura component

Tags: lightning-development

Is there a way to achieve Case Insensitive comparison for Strings in lightning aura components 
As per the Salesforce documentation the only expression available to compare is **equals()**
There's no expression as **equalsIgnoreCase()** available in lightning Aura.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{#equals(subcat.Name,subcat.Category_Text__c)}">
  -
  <aura:set attribute="else">
    {#subcat.Name}
  </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

I want the **isTrue** expression comparison to be Case Insensitive